# Have Automator open terminal and execute ssh command

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal, osx-yosemite, automator

How can one without using applescript have Automator open terminal and execute an ssh command?  I want to tie this to a dictation command so that I can simply speak a command and have terminal open and the ssh command executed.  I will then enter the password manually.